# What test cases might give the wrong result for the following code?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write an algorithm for the following problem:
Given an array of n integers (a1, a2,...,an), find the special number k such that if all integers in the array are subtracted from k, then the sum of all the differences will be zero, i.e., (k-a1)+...+(k-an)=0. If no such number exists, then print "NO SOLUTION"

Here's the algorithm that I came up with

```
    double k=(double) array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i <n ; i++) {
        k+=(double) array[i];
    }

    if ( (k/n) % 1.0 == 0)
        System.out.println((int)k/n);
    else
        System.out.println("NO SOLUTION");
```

The values of n and array are entered by the user.

After I submit my code on hackerrank I get 8/10 correct test cases.
I can't see what cases that I'm missing, can someone help?

Comment: Mod by 1? This always produces 0?

Comment: @CaiusJard Not when k/n has a decimal part.  I used mod by one to make sure that k/n is an integer. Since all the elements of the array are integers then k must be an integer.

Comment: Do you mean like "what if the array is zero elements long?" (The code crashes). Why does the user supply n when this seems to be the array.Length? You said that k just has to be a number, why do you code up to insist it be an integer? For an array of 4,5 the number to subtract from to sum to zero is 4.5 and this doesn't seem to be denied by the rule "special number k such that if all integers in the array are subtracted from it". Essentially this challenge seems to be "find the average of an array of ints" - perhaps some int set that produces an number unstable float math/sums to 0.000001 ?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my question, as I was having a long day. Anyway let me explain this better; in the original problem n >0, therefore it isn't the length of the array that is the issue. As to why the user should enter n, it's so hackerrank can check more than a test case based on n (I'm in a training program that uses hackerrank. The instructor told us not to worry about the value of n being a 0). 

It's also my fault that I didn't explain that K has to be an integer. It's part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following code have a different result:

```
if(array==null || array.length == 0)
  System.out.println("NO SOLUTION");

double s=0;
for(int x: array)
  s+=x;

int avg = (int)(s/array.length);


if(avg == s/array.length)
    System.out.println(avg);
else
    System.out.println("NO SOLUTION");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Surprisingly, this code works. But I still can't see how yours is any different than mine. I didn't check if the the array was empty or not and the code still works. So, that wasn't the issue.
Perhaps, it's like you said "some int set that produces an number unstable float". Tbh, I didn't know that this existed and I can't see how it could happen. I'll have to see my instructor and see the test cases that failed and debug them.
Regardless, thanks a lot!